# How to access separate yui object from one another

Tags: yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

In "Start Workflow" page, "Start Workflow" form is generated from Form-Engine.

> I want to disable "Start Workflow" button when submitting form. When
>   callback, I want to enable this button.

In start-workflow.js, I can get this button by using

```
var submitButton = Dom.get(this.generateId + "-form-submit-button");
submitButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

But adding attribute "`disabled`" does not work in IE8 as button can even click. But it works in mozilla. But by using yui disabled,

`this.submitElements[0].set("disabled", true);` can be work.

The problem is that **how can I access Alfresco.FormUI(form.js) from Alfresco.component.StartWorkflow(start-workflow.js). Since they are separate yui object, I do not know how to access from one another.**

If you know, let me share your knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other component extends `Alfresco.component.Base` then it should have registered its presence on the page when it was instantiated.

You can then use `Alfresco.util.ComponentManager` ([docs](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-4.0.e/symbols/Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.html)) to retrieve the instance you want, e.g. if it is the only instance on the page,

```
var otherCmpt = Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.findFirst(p_sName)
```

where `p_sName` is the full name of the class as a String value, e.g. `"Alfresco.FormUI"`.